# Text animation pause and continue

Tags: jquery

So the below code is what I am using to have text slide in from left and the right at the same time. Unfortunately, I'm unable to pause the first animation after it's complete. I need a delay after the first set of animations.

I've tried the delay, setTimeout and setInterval functions but nothing seems to work (thanks @evan for the ideas). Does anyone know how I could accomplish this?

Here is a example of what the code below does: [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/xPXqV/1/)

```
$(function() {

    var num = 0;
    var wordTrue = true;
    var words = [
        {left: "SLAM", right: "FACE"},
        {left: "BOOST", right: "JAMZ"}
     ];   

    var fadel = $('#fadel');
    var fader = $('#fader');

    animate();

    function animate() {
        var leftword = words[num].left;
        var rightword = words[num].right;

        var first = leftword.slice(0, leftword.indexOf(" "));

        first = "<span class=\"g h\">" + first + "</span>";

        var lastWords = leftword.substring(leftword.indexOf(" ") + 1);

        var finalString = first + lastWords;

    fadel
        .stop()
        .css('top', '18px')
        .css('left', '0')
        .css('opacity', 0)
        .text(leftword).show();

    fader
        .stop()
        .css('top', '68px')
        .css('left', '400px')
        .css('opacity', 0)
        .text(rightword).show();

    fadel.animate({
        opacity: 1,
        left: '150px'
        }, 2700, function() {
            fadel.fadeOut("fast", function() {
            queueNext().delay(5000);
        });
    });

    fader.animate({
        opacity: 1,
        left: '250px'
    }, 2700, function() {  
            fader.fadeOut("fast");
        });
    }

    function queueNext() {
        if (++num == words.length)
        num = 0;

        animate();
    }
});
```

Comment: Please provide a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) example.

Comment: So you want a delay each time `animate()` is called?

Answer (score 0):

Use [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setTimeout) in your `queueNext` function.

```
function queueNext()
{
    if (++num == words.length)
        num = 0;
    setTimeout(animate, 3000); //delay duration (in milliseconds)
}
```

DEMO: 
http://jsfiddle.net/dirtyd77/xPXqV/2/